# Add post with category programmatically

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the `wp_insert_post()` function to create a post with a customized data but I am unable to add categories and featured image in the post
my code is below:

```
        $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $leadTitle,
        'post_content' => $leadContent,
        'post_status' => $postStatus,
        'post_date' => $timeStamp,
        'post_author' => $userID,
        'post_type' => $postType,
        'post_category' => array('language'),
        'tags_input' => array('Language',"Temp")
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Please find my answer, is it working for you, let me know in case of any query.

Answer (score 1):

The `post_category` parameter for [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) should be provided as array of category id's, if your categories has hierarchical structure(for default post types it's so):

```
'post_category' => array(90, 100)
```

Also, make sure the id's in the array provided as `int`.

More detailed you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/).

If you added the image in the `Media Library` of your website, you can use it as attachment for your post/page using it's `ID` like:

```
'_thumbnail_id' => 110
```

If you don't have it, then first need to add image as `attachment` type using [`wp_insert_attachment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/) function.

So, your function will look:

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $leadTitle,
    'post_content' => $leadContent,
    'post_status' => $postStatus,
    'post_date' => $timeStamp,
    'post_author' => $userID,
    'post_type' => $postType,
    'post_category' => array(99),
    'tags_input' => array('Language',"Temp"),
    '_thumbnail_id' => 110
    );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check below code:

$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_title']    = 'My post';
$my_post['post_content']  = 'This is my post.';
$my_post['post_status']   = 'publish';
$my_post['post_author']   = 1;
$my_post['post_category'] = array(0);
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );"
```

Or

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $leadTitle,
    'post_content' => $leadContent,
    'post_status' => $postStatus,
    'post_date' => $timeStamp,
    'post_author' => $userID,
    'post_type' => $postType,
    'post_category' => array('language'),
    'tags_input' => array('Language',"Temp")
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```